# How to get the last-modified or the creation time of a document crawled and indexed by nutch+solr?

Tags: solr, web-crawler, document, nutch, last-modified

I need to get the last-modified or the creation time of a document under some intranet crawled and indexed by nutch+solr?
I tried using the Metadata.LAST_MODIFIED field but it returned me null. I
need them while displaying my search results. The Date is returning the date of crawling.
I am not very experienced on this, so any help is welcome! Thank you very much.
Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found here a possible answer, but is not exactly what I am searching for, it's more complicated than this, but can be helpful for others:
www.ryanpfister.com/2009/04/how-to-sort-by-date-with-nutch/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the URL you tested did not return a Last-Modified response header. Most web pages do not return this information. Since it's in your Intranet, I suggest testing it with some tool (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools' network monitor) to see if the header is actually returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it did  not returned that, but I can see the field in the schema file and also in the solr (index) which is empty. I would be interested now on how I can see what data is pushing nutch into crawl DB segments. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. 
If you want to see the metadata for a specific page in a segment, use `nutch readseg -get`.
If you want to understand how Nutch decides what metadata is written in which case, you have to look at the code, or better yet, debug it.